# In Chrome, is it possible to see the body of a failed WebSocket upgrade?

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, httpresponse

I'd like to see the body of a non-101 response, but I don't see it anywhere. I'd like to see what particular error occurred on my WebSocket server without having to set up SSL decryption in Wireshark.